# What permissions are required to be able to choose and select PDF files from a phone's storage without connection to a server in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-permissions

I am trying to create an application that will allow users to get an overview of all the PDF files (PDF files only) in their phone's storage on my app and they should be able to select any of the PDF files of their choice to be able to read only. The user should be able to do this without an internet connection, so my app will not be a client app. My app has to work for sdk 21 and all above sdks. This is my current code so far in my MainActivty.java class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private PdfAdapter pdfAdapter;
    private List<File> pdfList;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        runtimePermission();
    }

    private void runtimePermission() {
        Dexter.withContext(MainActivity.this).withPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse permissionGrantedResponse) {
                        displayPdf();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse permissionDeniedResponse) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission is Required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permissionRequest, PermissionToken permissionToken) {
                        permissionToken.continuePermissionRequest();
                    }
                }).check();

    }

    public ArrayList<File> findPdf (File file)
    {
        ArrayList<File> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        File[] files = file.listFiles();

        for (File singleFile: files)
        {
            if (singleFile.isDirectory() && singleFile.isHidden()) {
                arrayList.addAll(findPdf(singleFile));
            }
            else {
                if (singleFile.getName().endsWith(".pdf")){
                    arrayList.add(singleFile);
                }
            }
        }
        return arrayList;
    }
    private void displayPdf() {
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 3));
        pdfList = new ArrayList<>();
        pdfList.addAll(findPdf(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()));
        pdfAdapter = new PdfAdapter(this, pdfList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(pdfAdapter);
    }
}
```

The only uses permission I have in my manifest file is READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, I am using 'com.karumi:dexter:6.2.3' as my implementation for runtime permission as it simplifies the process. My minSDK is 32, targetSDK 32 and compileSDK is 33. I also have a PDFAdapter and PDFViewHolder as the other two java classes in my android studio project. What changes should I make in order to achieve my goal?

Comment: stack overflow isn't your platform to decide what goes on. someone asks how much or whatever they want as long as it follows the guidelines. @blackapps

Answer (score 1):

For Android 11 (R) and above, add the permission to the app’s manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

For Android Versions Below 11, add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Check For Permissions At Runtime

```
public void checkStoragePermissions(){
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R){
        //Android is 11 (R) or above
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
            Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", this.getPackageName(), null);
            intent.setData(uri);
            storageActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
            storageActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
        }
    }else {
        //Below android 11
        Dexter.withContext(MainActivity.this).withPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse permissionGrantedResponse) {
                    displayPdf();
                }

                @Override
                public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse permissionDeniedResponse) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission is Required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permissionRequest, PermissionToken permissionToken) {
                    permissionToken.continuePermissionRequest();
                }
            }).check();
    }
}

private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> storageActivityResultLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult o) {
                        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                            //Android is 11 (R) or above
                            if(Environment.isExternalStorageManager()) {
                                //Manage External Storage Permissions Granted
                                displayPdf();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Storage Permissions Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need any permission.

And why you are talking about a server is a puzzle.

(This answer is given looking at the subject of your post only).

Comment: So I don't need runtime permission at all for any sdk from 21 and above? How come all the pdf file reading apps that I ever download ask for access to storage permission? If you know the answer then where is your solution?